# pandas stacked bar does not use x-location

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working with the following pandas dataframe:

```
index       A           B      day
0           0.900       NaN    11
1           0.600       NaN    12
2           0.600       NaN    13
3           0.600       NaN    14
4           0.300       NaN    15
5           1.278       NaN    18
6           0.429      0.70    19
7           0.240      1.00    20
8           0.279      0.95    21
9           0.330       NaN    22
10          0.369       NaN    25
11          0.285       NaN    26
12          0.594      0.65    27
13          0.741      0.50    28
14          0.855       NaN    29
15          0.399       NaN    32
16          1.140       NaN    33
17          1.383       NaN    34
```

I'd like to plot a bar, where for each day the amount of A and B are stacked. This works with `df.plot.bar(x='days', stacked=True)`, but Pandas barplot does not take into account the uneven spacing in the x-variable: it puts each bar at the same distance from the previous, even though the difference in 'days' is not continuous.

The same plot, but with `kind='area'` or `kind='line'` does the x-spacing correctly, but fails to stack A and B in a clear way.

Is this expected Pandas behavior, and is there any way to force the stacked bar to use the index for placement? I'd rather not go down the route of manually stacking bars (https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html), since the dataframe will have more columns than A and B in the future.

[Figure that shows the three types of plots, with the stacked bar on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvDyp.png)

Comment: Hi Anne, welcome to SO. Please read something about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this particular case it will be nice to share the `df.to_dict()`.

Comment: You can use `ax.set_xticks()` ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html)) to tell matplotlib where and what you want your x tick values and labels to be. You can pass in the full range and it should plot only where x values exist and leave the others blank

Comment: the continuous spacing in matplotlib is more of a default behavior. It will change if you tell it to do so!

Comment: @d_kennetz I'm unsure why this is default behavior only in the bar plots, but not in line or area plots from Pandas - see the figure attached. Is there a specific way to toggle this on/off?

Comment: It makes perfect sense, as the X-axis in a bar plot is considered to be categorical data. They are evenly spaced because pandas is treating a bar plot how it is supposed to be treated: as comparing a value across categories of data. In this case your category is "days"

Answer (score 2):

A pandas bar plot is a categorical plot. It will show bars at successive positions 0,1,..N-1. Line- or area plots are numerical plots, they show on an actual scale.

### A. Use matplotlib

One option is indeed to use a matplotlib `bar` plot, since this is numeric in nature as well.

```
u = """index       A           B      day
0           0.900       NaN    11
1           0.600       NaN    12
2           0.600       NaN    13
3           0.600       NaN    14
4           0.300       NaN    15
5           1.278       NaN    18
6           0.429      0.70    19
7           0.240      1.00    20
8           0.279      0.95    21
9           0.330       NaN    22
10          0.369       NaN    25
11          0.285       NaN    26
12          0.594      0.65    27
13          0.741      0.50    28
14          0.855       NaN    29
15          0.399       NaN    32
16          1.140       NaN    33
17          1.383       NaN    34"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df["day"], df["A"])
ax.bar(df["day"], df["B"], bottom=df["A"])

plt.show()
```

[image]

### B. Use pandas index

If you do not consider this to be an option, you can use the dataframe index to plot the bars. This works here, because the days are all integers. To this end you may create a dataframe with all possible indices between the minimum and maximum day and fill it with the values of the original data. Then plot it via pandas plotting wrapper.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"], index=range(df["day"].min(),df["day"].max()+1))
df2.update(df.set_index("day"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df2.plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]